# Altura da página com javascript, levar o usuário até um ponto da página

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Olá, como posso desenvolver uma forma de levar o usuário até um trecho (altura) da página quando clicar em um link!

**Exemplo:**

`<div class="roupas"> </div>
 <div class="bolsas"> </div>
 <div class="calçados"> </div>
 <a>Roupas</a>`

Ao clicar no link a pessoa vai para div roupas

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Será isto? Apreveite os atributos [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

```js
$('[data-vestuario]').on('click', function() {
  var seccao = $(this).data('vestuario');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(seccao).offset().top, // animar pag até à distancia entre a secção correspondente e o topo da página
  });
});
```

```css
span {
 display:inline-block;
 margin: 0 30px;
 color: red;
}
div {
  height: 600px; /* Isto é só pelo exemplo, não aconselho a usar isto num proj real */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span data-vestuario="#roupas">Roupas</span>
<span data-vestuario="#sapatos">Sapatos</span>
<span data-vestuario="#cuecas">Cuecas</span>

<div id="roupas">
  Secção das roupas
</div>
<div id="sapatos">
  Secção das sapatos
</div>
<div id="cuecas">
  Secção das cuecas
</div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado no final ficou assim mando o submit por get (php) para a página e dependendo do retorno aplico um javascript assim: $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:5}, 'slow');

Comment: hehe de nada @user50404, ainda bem que ajudei

Answer (score -1):

Olá.
Você poderia utilizar o componente scroolspy do Boostrap.
Veja [Documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Comment: Sem a utilização de Boostrap como posso fazer isso? De forma mais "nativa" (espero ser o termo correto) Muito Obrigado @Renan